# Non-EU citizen applying UK visa, return ticket from France, should I book a return from UK for UK visa appliation?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, eu

I'm a non-EU citizen, I have valid Schengen and USA visa at the moment. (I also had many Schengen visas before).

I'm going on a trip next month but my flights are first one to London and return from Paris. (I'll spend 5 days in London then we will go to Paris, so return ticket from there)
I'm about to apply UK visa for the first time, I have bookings in France and train ticket reservation from London to Paris, should I bother booking a return ticket from London or should I just try to explain my return will be from another country.

My companions also applied and they didn't provide return ticket from London (but from Paris), and since I gave their names as travelling together guess I should do the same?

Comment: You'll need to show how you plan to leave the UK, but that doesn't have to be a return ticket.

Comment: Your train ticket from London-Paris should be sufficient. You need to show how you plan to leave the UK, but you are not required to leave by air!

Answer (score 1):

You **do not** need to have a return ticket from London. All they will need to see is you are leaving the UK and as you say you have a Eurostar ticket followed by a return ticket from Paris which should work. I am a non-EU citizen and didnt have any problems showing a London - Dubai - Delhi return.